# How to determine which colour space to use in pdf to image conversion?

Tags: pdf, docker, imagemagick

I have a simple script that converts pdf files into png files.

It essentially run this `convert` command:

```
convert -strip -quiet -quality 100 -alpha off -density 165% -scene 1 -colorspace sRGB "/data/input.pdf" "/output/image.png"
```

However I have this one particular pdf file which has a white background like this:

[image]

and the outcome looks like this:

[image]

You can see the white background has turned into black.

I can fix it by simply switching the parameter to `-colorspace cmyk`

I ran `identify` on the file but it does not indicate `cmyk`

```
> identify /data/input.pdf
/data/input.pdf PDF 1920x1080 1920x1080+0+0 16-bit sRGB 2.07246MiB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

**My question is:**

How do I know when to use sRGB space (which works until this file comes along) and when to use cmyk?

**EDIT:**

The file [can be viewed here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzMTD_LNX0z_cl9lN2pVbzI5SWc)

ImageMagick version information

```
> convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.9-19 Q16 x86_64 2017-10-24 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2017 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC OpenMP 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fontconfig freetype gvc jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr lzma openexr png tiff wmf x xml zlib
```

Here is the dockerfile that replicates my dev environment:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04


RUN apt-get update --fix-missing 
RUN apt-get install -y libmagickwand-dev wget


WORKDIR '/src'
ENV IMAGEMAGICK_VERSION 6.9.9-19
RUN wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/archive/${IMAGEMAGICK_VERSION}.tar.gz -O ${IMAGEMAGICK_VERSION}.tar.gz && \
    tar -zxvf ${IMAGEMAGICK_VERSION}.tar.gz && \
    cd ImageMagick-${IMAGEMAGICK_VERSION} && \
    ./configure && \
    make && \
    make install && \
    ldconfig /usr/local/lib


WORKDIR /
COPY *.pdf /
COPY *.sh /
```

Full set of files can be found here: https://github.com/kongakong/StackoverflowCode/tree/convert-pdf-imagemagic/imagemagick/46900660

Comment: There's no meaningful test on a file by file basis. In PDF, color spaces are set on an image by image basis.

Comment: You have posted JPGs and not PDF files. So it is hard to test your command and suggest a fix.

Comment: @fmw42 I don't think SO allows me to attach files

Comment: `@AnthonyKong` Post to some free hosting service and put a link here. Be sure you choose a place that does not change the format or zip it first.

Comment: @fmw42 I have added a link to the question

Comment: @fmw42 I have added a dockerfile to the question. More support files can be found in the github link in the updated question

Comment: `@AnthonyKong` I don't think I can be of much more help, but to point out that ImageMagick needs Ghostscript to process PDF files. So if you have not included Ghostscript into your Dockerfile, then that could be the issue. Please note my Answer below and the change in the convert command line from your version.

Comment: @fmw42 Thanks for your help. I have verified `gs` is installed

Comment: I suspect the original has an alpha layer. What appears to be white is actually transparent.

Answer (score 1):

OK. I have downloaded your PDF file. Your file is sRGB. It has transparency. If you turn transparency off using -alpha off, it will have a black background, since transparency is transparent black in this case, i.e. rgb(0,0,0,0). If you want a white background, then you must flatten the result against a white background. So this works fine for me.

```
convert -quiet -density 165 -colorspace sRGB color-p9.pdf[0] -background white -flatten color-p9.png
```

Using png output works for me but the file is too big to post. So I have converted it to jpg, simply to display here. You can use png for output on your system and set the quality as per my link describing png quality in my previous post.

[image]

Comment: I am still getting a black background. My imagemagick version is 6.9.9-19.

Comment: I was using IM 6.9.9.20 Q16 Mac OSX and it works fine for me. Do you have Ghostscript installed and IM can find it (convert -version should list gs or gslib). If so what version of Ghostscript? I am using gs --version which says 9.21). What is your platform? Did you use `convert -quiet -density 165 -colorspace sRGB color-p9.pdf[0] -background white -flatten color-p9.png`

Comment: I am actually using docker and running imagemagick on ubuntu 16.04. Let me come up with a simplified dockerfile later so you could try

Comment: My guess is that Docker does not know or have Ghostscript. Do you know how to check -- convert -version or convert -list configure. See if the delegates include gs or gslib. Unfortunately, I do not know Docker. Are you sure Docker has IM 6.9.9.19?

Answer (score 0):

Your input example is JPG and not PDF. Can you post the original pdf as a link?

If you do not want to use profiles, then you should just convert to sRGB using -colorspace sRGB before reading your input PDF. If the image is CMYK then it will convert to SRGB. If it is already sRGB, then it does not hurt to have it there.

Note that -quality is different for PNG output than for JPG. So the values you need are different. Also it should be placed after reading the PDF, since it applies to the output. See http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality

Also density is not specified in percent. It is a numerical value for dpi (or dotspercentimeter). So -units should be specified if you want to be sure.

Also if your PDF has transparency, and you turn alpha off, you will get black for the background, since transparent is transparent black.

So something like:

```
convert -quiet -density 165 -colorspace sRGB "/data/input.pdf[0]" -alpha off -quality XX "/output/image.png"
```

I have added the page id as [0] to the PDF to get the first page in place of using -scene. Either should be OK. You can add -strip if you want, but after reading the PDF.

If you want to see what colorspace your PDF file has, then you should check it before processing.

```
convert image.pdf -format "%[colorspace]" info:
```

See http://www.imagemagick.org/script/escape.php

You can also check for profiles using:

```
convert image.pdf -format "%[profiles]" info:
```

and also

```
convert image.pdf -format "%[profile:icc]" info:
convert image.pdf -format "%[profile:icm]" info:
```